# Enable new content types to use as newsletter

Tags: emails

I am using the simplenews module in order to create newsletters and enable users to subscribe to those. By following the instructions in the readme file it says:

Enable new content types to use as newsletter:
Structure > edit content type > Publishing options

What I did, I created a new content type and in the Publishing options I enabled the "Use as a simplenews newsletter" option.

Is this correct? Or should I have gone into one of the existing content types and selected this checkbox instead?

Also, 
ENABLE SIMPLENEWS BLOCK

With the Simplenews block users can subscribe to a newsletter.

Enable a Simplenews block per Newsletter category:
Structure > Newsletters > edit newsletter category

In my block structure I have the following available to me:
Newsletter: Multi Subscription
Newsletter: Newsletter

Enabling Newsletter: Newsletter displays nothing. SHould it?
Enablinb Newsletter: Multi Subscription displays an option of subscribing to available newsletters. But I only have one newsletter so it's a bit misleading.

What settings have I stuffed up in order for the Newsletter: newsletter block to not display anything, but to instead have a multi subscription block?

Answer (score 1):

The main options are the defaults.  So when you edit a content type all the options you turn on/off are the defaults for newly created content.  Any content that has already been created will need to be edited and re-saved with that option selected.  If you have a lot, I suggest using VBO.

Comment: Thanks for that @iLLin

Are you able to clarify what exactly you mean?
I am developing a new site, so there is no content to begin with and all the newsletters will be created from scratch.

Comment: When you create a content type, you have defaults, like is it published, is it published to home page.  Each piece of content that you create will inherit these options.  When you create content you can override the defaults if you want to or not.  Just go in and create a content type and content and you will understand :)

Comment: Thanks @iLLin

WHat I originally did was created a new content type for simplenews/newsletter. I take it this is correct? The simplenews instructions sort of told me differently but if what I did is correct then great :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if you create new content types or make existing ones to newsletter issues. That's up to you.

If you checked the block checkbox and displayed the block and it doesn't show anything, then something is not working correctly. Can't say what exactly that would be, if you are sure that you followed the instructions directly, try open a support or bug report in the module. Before you would do that, I suggest you try to do the same on a clean, new Drupal installation to see if it works there or not. If it does, then probably something else on your site conflicts.